# Cocos2d-x CCScrollview is scrolling upside down

Tags: android, c++, iphone, eclipse, cocos2d-x

Greetings Stackoverflow,

I am currently trying to implement a scrolling menu into a cocos2d-x game that I am developing. The problem is that the items are scrolling in the opposite direction that I want. For example, if I drag my finger from the bottom of the screen, to the top, the sprite will bounce back to its original position.

And if I drag my finger from the top to the the bottom, the sprite will follow my finger (until it reaches the boundary).

This is my code:

```c
    /////////////////////
    //SCROLL VIEW + LAYER
    CCLayer *layer = CCLayer::create();
    layer->setContentSize( CCSizeMake( winSize.width, winSize.height ) );
    layer->addChild( menu );

    scrollView = CCScrollView::create();
    scrollView->retain();
    scrollView->setContentSize( CCSizeMake ( layer->getContentSize().width,  layer->getContentSize().height ) );
    scrollView->setDirection( CCScrollViewDirectionVertical );
    scrollView->setPosition( ccp( 0,0 ) );
    scrollView->setContainer( layer );

    this->addChild(scrollView);

    scrollView->setContentOffset( CCPointZero );
```

Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated. If you have any other work around for creating a scrolling menu with another approach, I would love to hear.

Thank you!

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: what is the type of "menu"? And also you should use function 'scrollView->setViewSize(CCSize)' to set scrollview's touch aera.

Comment: The type of menu is CCMenu. The touch area is working as intended.

Comment: Did this code work well on iOS platform?This may give you some tips. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/18/topics/17298?r=22307

Comment: I haven't tried it on an iOS platform yet, but I am afraid it will work the same as it does on my Android device. I have tried the things that were suggested in that thread, but without success. I actually replied to that thread. Thank you for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer: [cocos2dx/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView/CCScrollView.cpp](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView/CCScrollView.cpp#L354)

Specifically [`CCScrollView::minContainerOffset`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView/CCScrollView.cpp#L359) and [`CCScrollView::maxContainerOffset`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView/CCScrollView.cpp#L354)

`CCScrollView` works in *OpenGL coordinates* (as opposed *window coordinates*) - values are relative to (left, bottom) with positive Y axis going upwards. Also, keep in mind the scroll view's positioning and the *container* are anchored (`CCNode::setAnchorPoint`) to (left, bottom).

When you scroll down (move/pull the content upwards to see content below the cut/clip), you see the content below the bottom edge of the screen but it bounces back the moment you let go of the touch/drag because `maxContainerOffset` returns `(0, 0)` and you've just tried to move to a positive content offset.

[image: Coordinates of CCScrollView and the container]

The diagram shows the state of the *scrollview* and the *container* when they're created/initialized. This is the state or the coordinates to "think in" when setting up and positioning the *child elements* and *container*. The gray rectangle (left, bottom) shows the valid region for scrolling the *container*. Imagine the container's anchor point moves inside it.

To see the container scrolled to the top to begin with (what you'd expect when working in *window coordinates*), set the content offset accordingly (immediately after setting it up). This will give the expected results/behavior.

```
scrollView->setContentOffset(ccp(0.f, (scrollViewHeight-scrollContainerHeight)), false);
```

A more complete example is in the edited code below.

1. <s>A "fix" to allow scrolling in the window coordinate (positive Y axis downwards) may be to adjust the extension,  this would require you to rebuild the cocos2dx library and will affect all projects (even other sample code you may try).</s>

   ```
   /*
   // (StackOverflow Post Edit: This hack is not required.)
   CCPoint CCScrollView::maxContainerOffset()
   {
       // Default CCPointZero;
       return ccp(0.0f, m_pContainer->getContentSize().height*m_pContainer->getScaleY() - m_tViewSize.height);
   }
   CCPoint CCScrollView::minContainerOffset()
   {
       // Default Y = m_tViewSize.height - m_pContainer->getContentSize().height*m_pContainer->getScaleY();
       return ccp(m_tViewSize.width - m_pContainer->getContentSize().width*m_pContainer->getScaleX(), 
              0.f);
   }
   */
   ```
2. <s>A **less intrusive** *hack*, is to scale the *ScrollView* instance to -1 and the *children* of the *container node* also to -1. You also have to reposition the *child nodes* taking into account the inverse scale. The result of the scaling at both levels is the content (*child nodes*) are viewed straight (not flipped). The result of scaling the *ScrollView* to -1 is that the scroll happens for you in the expected direction. Note though this "fix" will flip scrolling in the X axis as well and hence is *only* suitable if you wish to scroll vertically (`CCScrollViewDirectionVertical`).</s>

   ```
   CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
   CCLayer* scrollContainer = CCLayer::create(); // Container for the scroll view
   scrollContainer->setAnchorPoint(CCPointZero); // CCScrollView does this too when it's set as the container.

   // Content for the container
   CCSprite *tallContentA = CCSprite::create("TallContentA.png");
   tallContentA ->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width*0.5f, winSize.height*0.9f));
   CCSprite *tallContentB = CCSprite::create("TallContentB.png");
   tallContentB ->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width*0.5f, winSize.height*0.1f));
   scrollContainer->addChild(tallContentA, 2);
   scrollContainer->addChild(tallContentB, 2);

   float scrollContainerHeight = tallContentA->getContentSize().height + tallContentB->getContentSize().height;
   scrollContainer->setPosition(CCPointZero);
   scrollContainer->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(winSize.width, scrollContainerHeight*1.05f));

   // Set up scroll view
   CCScrollView* scrollView = CCScrollView::create(winSize, scrollContainer);
   scrollView->setPosition(CCPointZero);
   scrollView->setDirection(CCScrollViewDirectionVertical);
   // ScrollView initializes at the (left, bottom). The container also gets positioned relative to that and goes Y-up.
   // Pre-set it to the value CCScrollView::minContainerOffset will return when it's scrolled to the top
   // (note, this is a negative number, indicating the touch moving downwards, i.e. it's pre-scrolled such that the top of the content is visible when we begin)
   scrollView->setContentOffset(ccp(0.f, (winSize.height-scrollContainerHeight*1.05f)), false);
   /*
   // (StackOverflow Post Edit: This hack is not required.)
   // Hack: CCScrollView's maxContainerOffset is (0, 0) and minContainerOffset is (difference between view and content size which is negative)
   // It's designed to be (left, bottom) based and positive scrolling means showing stuff above the top of the screen.
   // Since we're using it in terms of Window coordinates ((left, top) based), we scale the scroll view
   // and it's container's children by -1 and position the children differently
   // (eg. Y position winSize.height*0.1f was changed to winSize.height*0.9f)
   // We can't just set the scroll view's Y scale to -1 because CCNode::getScale asserts that X and Y scale must be the same.
   scrollView->setScale(-1.f);
   tallContentA->setScale(-1.f);
   tallContentB->setScale(-1.f);
   */

   addChild(scrollView);
   ```

<s>Also note that the two fixes mentioned above are *mutually exclusive*, do *not* apply *both*.</s>

[Answer](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/18/topics/17298?r=27221#message-27221) now on the cocos2d-x forum too.

Comment: Hi @PAT, I was having some problems with your solution. I posted it in cocos2d-x forum, would you please help? Thanks! http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/18/topics/17298?r=40599#message-40599

Answer (score 3):

@Zennichimaro,

@PAT's answer is correct and is essentially a simplified version

With that in mind, note that 3 things are important:

1. `CCScrollView::setViewSize()` - you clearly missed out this one, it has to be the width and height of your viewable space (the blue box, I think it is your entire windowSize if you want it fullscreen)
2. `CCScrollView::setContentSize()` - this is different from setContentOffset, looks like you've mistaken this to setContentOffset, anyway, this should be set to the size of the entire container (the red box, yours will probably be `ccp(windowSize.width,2496.0f)`)
3. `CCScrollView::setContentOffset()` - if you want to position it so that the topmost is visible initially, the minimum and maximum is specified by the small grey rectangle box in the answer (the grey box, yours will probably be `ccp(0.0f, windowSize.height-2496.0f)`)

Answer (score 3):

A shorter answer would be:

```
scrollView->setContentOffset(scrollView->minContainerOffset());
```

Since the anchor point is in the lower-left corner, the initial offset is not zero, but a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to make a scrollview like in mmo games chat tables (adds messages to bottom and auto scrolls to bottom of it) then maybe someone will find this useful:

part of the code of my ChatTableView.h

```
//tableView dataSource is vector of strings
class ChatTableView :public Layer, public TableViewDataSource, public TableViewDelegate
{
public:
    vector<string> n_msglist;
    TableView* pTableView;
    void addMsg(string text);
private:

};

//part of the code of my ChatTableView.cpp
void Init(){
    pTableView = TableView::create(this, VisibleRect::getVisibleRect().size, NULL);
    pTableView->setDirection(ScrollView::Direction::VERTICAL);
    pTableView->setVerticalFillOrder(TableView::VerticalFillOrder::TOP_DOWN);
    pTableView->setDelegate(this);
    pTableView->setBounceable(false);

} 
void ChatTableView::addMsg(string text){

    n_msglist.push_back(text); //adds string to vector
    pTableView->reloadData(); //reloads data with newly updated vector and scroll back to top
    pTableView->setContentOffset(pTableView->maxContainerOffset()); //scrolls to bottom
}
```